# Fetching unique Value and no. of times of the Value

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

In a (using mysql)table one of my column(i.e. colour) is like :

```
|Color|
======
|Red  |
|Blue |
|Green|
|Red  |
|Green|
|Green|
|Red  |
|Red  |
```

After establishing,jdbc connection in my current jsp page: I'm trying to show the value in a pie chart(it's wriien in jscript,where I'll  putting the value from mysql) like :

```
|Color|no. of Times|
====================
|Red  |   4        |
|Blue |   1        |
|Green|   3        |
```

Buy I am not able to put values into the graph(I guess there is problem in by code):

```
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/apps","root","root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql2="select distinct(color) as COLOR from user_management order by device;";
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
String s = rs2.getString("color");
while(rs2.next()){
    String device = rs2.getString("color");
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(device);
    }
// I guess here will be some code for device value in String, say "s" 

String sql1 = "select count(case when color='"+s+"' then 1 end) as COLOR from user_management";
ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
System.out.println(sql1);
%>
```

then putting the resultset in piechart table

```
<table id="chartData">
  <% while(rs2.next()){ %>
  <% while(rs1.next()){ %>
    <tr>
      <th>DEVICE</th><th>NUMBER</th>
     </tr>

    <tr style="color: #0DA068">
      <td><%= rs2.getString("device")%></td><td><%= rs1.getString(1)%></td>
    </tr>

   <% }     
   %>
   <% }     
   %>
 </table>
```

Any inputs that how to fetch the column value in a chart where color-name as well as no. of color happens at a same time.

Comment: Please learn to separate the concerns. This is not a Java/JSP/Servlet problem at all. This is just a simple JDBC/SQL problem. You would have exactly the same problem when executing/testing the JDBC/SQL code independently in a normal Java application class with a `main()` method instead of straight in a JSP file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,Am I able to make you understand of issue ? Can it be achieve in this way... or where I'm going wrong..any inputs

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Color, count(*) AS times FROM colors GROUP BY Color;
```

Comment: Here in this jsp page I calling a javascript where I have to put resultset object of each attribute,which will show a piechart.In code I guess there will be a variation,I guess(dont need sql)

Comment: I don't see any Javascript in your question. My answer solves the problem of "how to fetch the column value in a chart where color-name as well as no. of color happens at a same time."

Comment: I have nt posted that part,Even that's query if I want to implement in this way,then how to...I guess the way I thought it can be done,......that's why I'm trying in this way,Any input 4m yourside..